# Scala equivalent of C#’s extension methods?

Tags: scala, extension-methods

In C# you can write:

```
using System.Numerics;
namespace ExtensionTest {
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static BigInteger Square(this BigInteger n) {
        return n * n;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        BigInteger two = new BigInteger(2);
        System.Console.WriteLine("The square of 2 is " + two.Square());
    }
}}
```

How would this simple [extension method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method) look like in Scala?

Answer (score 74):

The [Pimp My Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) pattern is the analogous construction:

```
object MyExtensions {
  implicit def richInt(i: Int) = new {
    def square = i * i
  }
}


object App extends Application {
  import MyExtensions._

  val two = 2
  println("The square of 2 is " + two.square)

}
```

---

Per @Daniel Spiewak's comments, this will avoid reflection on method invocation, aiding performance:

```
object MyExtensions {
  class RichInt(i: Int) {
    def square = i * i
  }
  implicit def richInt(i: Int) = new RichInt(i)
}
```

Comment: Warning: by using the `new { ... }` syntax, you're actually causing the compiler to infer a structural type for the `richInt` method, meaning that any invocations of `square` will be done using reflection (a performance killer).  It would be better to define a `RichInt` class which defines `square` and is returned from the `richInt` method.

Comment: @Support Add `class RichInt(i: Int) { def square = i * i }` to `MyExtensions` and do `new RichInt(i)` on the `richInt` method.

Comment: @Daniel, great, I have an answer with your comment.

Comment: @Daniel interesting! I did a small test, the version with the structural type is indeed much slower: http://www.scala-notes.org/2010/06/avoid-structural-types-when-pimping-libraries/

Comment: @Jesper You can even get a little less sneaky and do the following: `val a = new { def b() { error("") } }; a.b()`.  This way, you can inspect the stack trace.

Answer (score 67):

Since version 2.10 of Scala, it is possible to make an entire class eligible for implicit conversion

```
implicit class RichInt(i: Int) {
  def square = i * i
}
```

In addition, it is possible to avoid creating an instance of the extension type by having it extend AnyVal

```
implicit class RichInt(val i: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def square = i * i
}
```

For more information on implicit classes and AnyVal, limitations and quirks, consult the official documentation:

- http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html
- http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html

Comment: Note that case classes **cannot** be annotated with `implicit` keyword, because they have auto-generated companion object. For more information see documentation links provided by @megri.

Answer (score 10):

This would be the code after Daniel's  [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119580/scala-equivalent-of-csharps-extension-methods/3119671#3119671).

```
object MyExtensions {
    class RichInt( i: Int ) {
        def square = i * i
    }
    implicit def richInt( i: Int ) = new RichInt( i )

    def main( args: Array[String] ) {
        println("The square of 2 is: " + 2.square )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Scala we use the so-called (by the inventor of the language) *Pimp My Library* pattern, which is much discussed and pretty easy to find on the Web, if you use a string (not keyword) search.

Answer (score 2):

Scala 3 now has extension methods. Functionally it seems similar as expected to C# and Kotlin.

https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html
https://github.com/scala/scala
https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty

A recent (as of this post) pull shows the syntax being simplified. Stable version as of this post is still 2.x. But there is a 3.xRC, and I noticed Jetbrains already supports it in Idea, partially I assume.