# Convert Any to Double using asInstanceOf?

Tags: scala

Is there a supported way to achieve a conversion of any numeric type to a double. E.g.

```
   val i = 12345
   val f = 1234.5F
   val d = 1234.5D
   val arr = Array[Any](i,f,d)
   val anotherD = arr(0).asInstanceOf[Numeric].toDouble
```

Naturally the above code is not correct as given - since Numeric requires Type arguments.

```
scala>        val i = 12345
i: Int = 12345

scala>        val f = 1234.5F
f: Float = 1234.5

scala>        val d = 1234.5D
d: Double = 1234.5

scala>        val arr = Array[Any](i,f,d)
arr: Array[Any] = Array(12345, 1234.5, 1234.5)

scala>        val anotherD = arr(0).asInstanceOf[Numeric].toDouble
<console>:11: error: type Numeric takes type parameters
              val anotherD = arr(0).asInstanceOf[Numeric].toDouble
```

Now I realize the above may be achieved via match/case , along the following lines:

```
  (a, e) match {
    case (a : Double, e : Double) =>
        Math.abs(a - e) <= CompareTol
    case (a : Float, e : Float) =>
        Math.abs(a - e) <= CompareTol
    .. etc
```

But I was wondering if there were a means to more compactly express the operation.  This code is within TEST classes and efficiency is not an important criterion. Specifically: reflection calls are OK.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are on the JVM. The [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class does like what you want to achieve with the `doubleValue` method:

```
val arr = Array[Number](i,f,d)
val ds = arr.map(_.doubleValue())
```

Comment: Perfect for my use case

Answer (score 2):

This is horrible, and [probably not efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588208/what-are-the-performance-and-maintenance-considerations-of-using-scalas-structu), but it works (on your example) :p

```
scala> import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

scala> arr.map(_.asInstanceOf[{ def toDouble: Double }].toDouble)
res2: Array[Double] = Array(12345.0, 1234.5, 1234.5)
```

Comment: I am OK with ideas like this. There are times I do not want fancy/long code: in this case it is within a Testing Class and efficiency is not a criterion.