# How can I map across multiple elements (e.g. lookahead)?

Tags: scala

I have a List[Int], perhaps like this:

```
List(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9)
```

There will be occasional duplication (always 2, not more).  When there's a dup I want to merge the elements together with a function.  So in this simple example if my function is to add the 2 numbers together I'd get:

```
List(1,2,6,4,5,12,7,8,9)
```

What's a concise way to do this?  List.map() only looks at/transforms 1 element at a time.

Comment: duplicates will be always in continuation? as in they will be at the neighboring position only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.foldLeft` with new list as accumulator *(**assuming the list has duplicates next to each other**)*

```
def mergeDuplicates(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  list.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) {
    case (l, elem) if l.lastOption.contains(elem) =>
      l.dropRight(1) :+ (2 * elem)
    case (l, elem) =>
      l :+ elem
  }
}

println(mergeDuplicates(List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9))) 

// output List(1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 12, 7, 8, 9)
```

**using [extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297857/432903),**

```
implicit class ListOps(list: List[Int]) {
  def mergeDuplicates: List[Int] = {
    list.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) {
      case (l, elem) if l.lastOption.contains(elem) =>
        l.dropRight(1) :+ (2 * elem)
      case (l, elem) =>
        l :+ elem
    }
  }
}

val mergedList = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9).mergeDuplicates
println(mergedList)
```

Comment: I think it makes more sense to `foldRight` and pre-pend `::` rather than `foldLeft` and append `:+`. Especially when building a `List`.

Comment: Especially since `lastOption` is fairly O(n) on list, it would be much better to prepend and `headOption` and reverse at the end

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, you could use the [`List#unfold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#unfold[A,S](init:S)(f:S=%3EOption[(A,S)]):CC[A]) combined with [`List#span`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#span(p:A=%3EBoolean):(List[A],List[A])):

```
// val items = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9)
List.unfold(items) {
  case Nil  => None
  case rest => Some(rest.span(_ == rest.head))
}
.map(_.sum)
// List(1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 12, 7, 8, 9)
```

or even, coupled with `Scala 2.13`'s [`Option#unless`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#unless[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) builder:

```
List
  .unfold(items)(rest => Option.unless(rest.isEmpty)(rest.span(_ == rest.head)))
  .map(_.sum)
```

---

- Unfold uses an internal state which is initialized in our case with the list `List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9)` for which to sum consecutive duplicates.
- During each iteration, we `span` that internal state in order to find the heading consecutive items: `rest.span(_ == rest.head)` (which for instance during the third iteration on the `List(3, 3, 4, 5, ...)` internal state gives `(List(3, 3), List(5, 6, ...))`).
- Since `unfold` expects within each iteration an `Option` of a tuple whose first part is the new element to add to the list being built (during the first iteration for instance `List(1)`) and whose second part is the new value of the internal state (`List(2, 3, 3, ...)`), that span fits exactly that requirement.
- We keep iterating the same step until the internal list is empty, in which case returning `None` signals the `unfold` that we're finished and that the iteration has to stop.
- Finally, we replace grouped parts (`List(List(1), ..., List(3, 3), ...)`) by their sum with a simple `.map(_.sum)`. This can of course also be achieved within the unfolding at the cost of some additional boilerplate.