# Can implicits change the parameter multiplicity of a method at the call-site?

Tags: scala, parameters, implicit

My API prototype is the following:

I have third party API object named `ZResponseHandler` which has method

```
printZ(z:Z)
```

no I have the following:

```
case class X
case class Y 
case class Z(x:X,y:Y)
```

now when I use my API calling printZ method with new z instance it works OK.

```
ZResponseHandler.printZ(new Z(x,y))
```

but I would like to create something like this:

```
implicit def convertXYtoZ(x:X,y:Y):Z = new Z(x,y)

ZResponseHandler.printZ(x,y)
```

this code gives me compilation error `- too many arguments for method printZ:`

is there any way to make any implicit class which will accept printZ(x,y)?

Comment: Take a look at [the Magnet pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/). It may be more complexity than you want, but it can do this and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicits can be used *wrap* or ["pimp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913591/understanding-why-pimp-my-library-was-defined-that-way-in-scala) the receiver to decorate it with more methods.

```
class R {
  def m (s: String) = println(s)
}

// This uses an anonymous type, but it could also return
// `new RichR(r)` or similar as appropriate.
implicit def toRichR(r: R) = new {
    def m(a: String, b: String) = r.m(a + " " + b)
}

val r = new R()
r.m("hello", "world") // -> toRichR(r).m("hello", "world")
```

[Implicit classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/implicit-classes.html) (Scala 2.10+) also allow the above pattern to be written more clearly.

```
implicit class RichR(r: R) {
    def m(a: String, b: String) = r.m(a + " " + b)
}
```

---

*Objects* can also be "pimped" in Scala 2.10 (but not 2.8)

```
object R {
  def m (s: String) = println(s)
}

// uses TheObject.type
implicit def toRichR(_r: R.type) = new {
    // (could use _r.m instead of R.m)
    def m(a: String, b: String) = R.m(a + " " + b)
}

R.m("hello", "world") // -> toRichR(r).m("hello", "world")
```

(There are also implicit objects, but I could not get such to work without a common [non-object] base type.)

Comment: Thanks, and if m is defined in R companion object? will cause any problem?

Comment: @danny.lesnik In Scala 2.10 it's possible to decorate objects with methods as well; I've updated the post with an example.

Answer (score 2):

An implicit method will convert a single argument, so you can't change the arity (number of parameters). However, you might be able to get around this using a Tuple:

```
implicit def convertXYtoZ(t: (X,Y) ):Z = new Z(t._1, t._2)
ZResponseHandler.printZ(x,y)
```

Comment: This works even if you don't use double parentheses - Scala will look for an implicit to convert all the parameters as a tuple.